# clicking a dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, protractor, gulp-protractor

I will give "from dates" and "To dates" and hit a "create" button. The expected output is

1. N cases found from "from dates" to "to dates" with a download button
2. 0 cases found from "from dates" to "to dates" without a download button

In the 1st scenario :

```
<div data-ng-if="canDownload()" class="ng-scope"
<h3 class="ABC" id="summary">N cases ound from "from dates" to "to dates"
<a data-ng-href="URL" id="summaryHREF"
<button class="XYZ" type="submit">Download<
```

In the 2nd scenario :

```
<div data-ng-if="noCases()" class="ng-scope"
<h3 class="ABC" >0 cases ound from "from dates" to "to dates"
```

I am successful in testing the postive scenario(where cases found)

```
let notes = element(by.id("summary"));

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var flag = browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(notes), 5000, '**** There are cases to Download ****');

if(flag){

  this.downloadReg = element(by.xpath("//button[text()='Download']"));
  this.downloadReg.click();
}
else{
  console.log("No Cases found and Do Nothing");

}
```

How do I check if the "summary" text contains "0 cases found...." then do nothing or if the cases found, then click on the Dynamically generated Download button.

Comment: In the second scenario, the `h3` element doesn't have the "summary" id. Is this how it actually is or did you just forget to put it there?

Comment: That's how actually it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls try the below snippet,

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('#summary'))), 5000, '**** There are cases to Download ****').then(flag => {
      if(flag){
        this.downloadReg = element(by.xpath("//button[text()='Download']"));
        this.downloadReg.click();
      }else{
        console.log("No Cases found and Do Nothing");
      }
    });
```

Cheers!

Comment: I did almost the same by using count and when count is 1, the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use:
[ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement)

There's no need to use `if else` - when the test won't find expected test it'll fail on timeout.

Comment: will it accept the part of the text? Also the element "summary" is dynamically generated and for "0 cases" scenario there won't be any element like "summary"

Comment: would you mind giving an example of using textToBePresentInElement? I tried var flag = browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(notes), 5000, '0 cases found from 2019-02-19 to 2019-02-19');
 and condition on flag(if else) to click on the download, still did not work

Comment: You have the arguments in the wrong order. It should be `browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(notes, '0 cases found from'), 5000)`

Answer (score 0):

You could just check to see if the download button is present in the DOM first and then click on it. Otherwise, do nothing and move on.

This is assuming the `h3` element also has the `'summary'` id attribute in the second scenario.

```
const notes = element(by.id('summary'));
await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(notes), 5000);

const downloadBtn = element(by.buttonText('Download'));
const flag = await downloadBtn.isPresent();

if (flag) {
    await downloadBtn.click();
}
```

Comment: The h3 element wont be having the 'summary' id in the second scenario.

Comment: I have tried the proposed solution(without the first two lines as 'summary' id does not exist in the second scenario. The flag value is always coming true(flag value :ManagedPromise::916 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}) and gives error saying cannot find the download button

Comment: When I run the test it says syntax error: unexpected identifier "await" , I did remove it but still getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

1) Wait for the element to locate using expected conditions(EC)
2) use the cssContainingText('locator',"string")

or else

write the dynamic xpath using the following::